# Fill a region on a graph with no outline?

Tags: octave

I'd like to fill a region on a graph plotted with octave, without any outline:

The fill command accepts a color argument that it respects for the filled area, but it doesn't seem to accept the 'LineColor' property to change the color of the line it draws around the filled area...

e.g.

```
fill([1 2 3 3 2 1], [1 0.5 1 -1 -1 -1], [0.9,0.9,0.9]); # line is black
fill([1 2 3 3 2 1], [1 0.5 1 -1 -1 -1], [0.9,0.9,0.9], 'LineColor', 'r') # hangs
```

I'm using octave-3.4.0 on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch command should do the job

```
verts = [0.2 0.4; ...
         0.2 0.8; ...
         0.8 0.8; ...
         0.8 0.4];
faces = [1  2  3 4];
p = patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',verts,'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','none');
```

Of course you could also place it in one line ... ;-)

Comment: I get this error trying to use patch: `error: __go_draw_axes__: gnuplot (as of v4.2) only supports 3D filled triangular patches` (even if I reduce the face to three verts, and add a z-coordinate to the vertices).

Comment: With octave 3.2.4 on osx it is working, check octave by typing version

Comment: Ah, I have version 3.4.0, with gnuplot-4.4.3.